# COCOAPOD file not found for Xcode unit tests only

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods, plcrashreporter

I have added PLCrashReporter using POD

```
use_frameworks! 
pod 'PLCrashReporter'
```

I have imported following files in Briding Header to use in my swift project

```
#import <CrashReporter/CrashReporter.h>
#import <CrashReporter/PLCrashReport.h>
```

If I run the project, then I don't get any problem and it works as expected

If I do xcode unit-test I get the following error
(*Xcode->Product->Test*)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the pods separately for *Target* and *TargetTests*

Make the following changes in **POD** file

```
target ‘Target’ do
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!
pod 'PLCrashReporter'
end

target 'TargetTests' do
    platform :ios, ‘8.0’
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'PLCrashReporter'
end
```

Go to the ***Build Settings*** of TargetTests 
and set the value for “**Other Linker Flags**” as **$(inherited)**

Do a ***POD install*** then do ***Clean Build Folder*** and run